# Is it possible to create an automated PWA installation with user's consent?

Tags: google-chrome, progressive-web-apps, angular-hybrid

I have a web app and have built a respective Electron app for Windows. I want to do the same thing for both IOS and Android without dealing with stores. The app is fully web but it will be hosted only locally, both front-end and back-end. So every client will have its own server in its own intranet.

**The problem** is that I do not want to open the local IP in every client browser and do 'Add to homescreen' manually.

**The ideal approach** would be to have an automated way to create and install the PWA on various local IOS, Android devices just as you would install an application in Windows.

**My question:** Is it possible to automatically create a PWA without having to go through the manual 'Browser' way?

Comment: Did you find any answer to your situation?

Comment: @jpmorin not yet. I have postponed this functionality so I have no solution so far